# Sylius: Creating Product Combo, Promotional Package

Tags: sylius

I am new to Sylius, but have gone through all the documentation and it is a really nice, clean and elegant design (from a developers perspective).

One of the requirements of the project is to be able to sell products in combo/packages.

Say I have these products that are sold separately.

- Product 1: 19.99$
- Product 2: 30.00$
- Product 3: 10.00$

I want to be able to create a product combo, like a limited time offer that sells all those products in a package, with a total price of 30$.
Even if sold as a package, the system must keep them as if they were sold separately but as part of a promotional package.

I wasn't able to find anything on Sylius that could help me do this out of the box.

Any thoughts on a possible solution to this using Sylius as much as possible without requiring to create a custom solution?

Thank you,
Ermal.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use the promotions component for that? create a campaign where you use the rules:

- if product 1 is in cart
- then add product 2 and product 3 at a
  discounted price

Comment: That only works on the first addition, ie. when you already have them in the Cart. If you increase the number of the promotion product, the package deal item counts are not updated, there will still only be 1 of each.

Comment: then create two different campaigns:


- if product 1 qty 1 is in cart
- then add product 2 qty 1 and product 3 qty 1 at discount price


and another campaign:


- if product 1 qty 2 is in cart
- then add product 2 qty 2 and product 3 qty 2 at discount price


otherwise, you'll need to create a custom rule / action in terms of promotions.

Comment: Thanks, but we need multiple package deals, it would be a nightmare to create promotions with different quantities (1-2-3-4-...-n).
Ended up adding custom rule/action.